# Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, bool given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Llibres\formu5.php on line 24

Tags: php, html

Este es el codigo:

```
<html>

<?php
$usuario = "root";
$password = "";
$server = "127.0.0.1";
$basedatos = "libros";
?>

<?php
    if ($connex = mysqli_connect( $server, $usuario, "" )){

    echo "<p>MySQL le ha dado permiso a PHP para ejecutar consultas con este usuario</p>";

    } 

$consulta = "SELECT*FROM libros WHERE Nombre = '" .  $_POST["Busca"]."' OR 1Apellido = '" .  $_POST["Busca"]."' OR 2Apellido= '" .  $_POST["Busca"]."' OR Titulo = '" .  $_POST["Busca"]."' OR AñoPubli = '" .  $_POST["Busca"]."' OR ISBN = '" .  $_POST["Busca"]."'";
$connex = mysqli_connect($server, $usuario, $password, $basedatos);
$result = mysqli_query ($connex, $consulta);

mysqli_select_db($connex , $basedatos);
$datos= mysqli_query ($connex, $consulta);

while ($fila=mysqli_fetch_array($datos)){
echo "<p>";
echo "-"; 
echo $fila ["Nombre"];
echo "-"; 
echo $fila ["1Apellido"];
echo "-"; 
echo $fila ["2Apellido"];
echo "-"; 
echo $fila ["Titulo"];
echo "-"; 
echo $fila ["AñoPubli"];
echo "-"; 
echo $fila ["ISBN"];
echo "<p>";



}
?>
```

El error lo da en la linea 24 de código: `while ($fila=mysqli_fetch_array($datos))`
El fin de esta parte de código es ver el resultado de la busqueda en la página web, es decir hacer la busqueda de, en este caso un libro, y que en la web se vean los datos de este libro.
He estado mirando que puede ocurrir pero no he encontrado ninguna web que me de una buena respuesta.

Comment: Primero que nada, por que estás haciendo 2 `mysqli_query` de la `$consulta` ??

Comment: @Excorpion eso ha sido un error, ahora lo corregiré, gracias!